# When I only have one tab in the tabbedpane and check for its index an exception is thrown

Tags: java, exception, tabs

I only have one tab created and the following code throws an exception, is this due to the fact that I do not actually select the tab because I am already in the tab?

```
selectedIndex = this.tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex();
System.out.println("Tab index : " + selectedIndex);
```

Comment: Hi, please post the full stack trace.

Comment: `tabbedPane` is `null`

Comment: Can I use setSelectedIndex() to set it to 0 when initialized?